# Az-delivery Arduino uno programm uploading problem

Tags: upload, arduino-uno, bootloader

I'm new in the arduino world and have a  AZ-Delivery Microcontroller Board with
ATMega328. I downloaded and installed the ch340-treiber and burned the old bootloader with an original arduino uno. If I try to upload a programm with the Arduino IDE this error message occurs:

```
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x42
```

For burning the bootloader I connected the following pins on the Arduino Uno to the fake one

10--> RES

GND-->GND (between RES and GND there is a 10µF condensator)

11-->11

12-->12

13-->13

and the 5V-->5V

In the Arduino IDE I uploaded the ArduinoISP-programm to the original one and then tried burning the bootloader with
Arduino nano /right port/ATmega328P (old bootloader)-processor and Arduino as ISP-Programmer

beforehand I tried burning with     Arduino Uno/right port/Arduino as ISP but if uploading a test programm i get this:

```
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I updated the Arduino IDE.
Standard Arduino uno was OK but AzDelivery version wasn't reconized by the IDE.
I had the CH340 driver version 3.8. I tried the 3.4 version without success.
The solution for me was using the CH340 driver version 3.5.2019.1 that I got from https://www.arduined.eu/ch340-windows-10-driver-download/